# How to implement the shape of a slider's label in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to implement a label as shown in the picture
[image: Label required]

```
@Composable
fun SliderLabel(
    label: String,
    minWidth: Dp,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Text(
        text = label,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        color = Color.White,
        maxLines = 1,
        style =MaterialTheme.typography.labelMedium,
        modifier = modifier
            .background(
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)
            )
            .padding(4.dp)
            .defaultMinSize(minWidth = minWidth)
    )
}
```

What should i change in this code to achieve that pointy edge just below that square?

Comment: You can copy the source code of slider and show a tooltip at the slider thumb location using offset. the tool tip itself can be a path and a rectangle above it!

Comment: you need to create shape using path.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment, you need to create custom shape by implementing Shape interface from the jetpack compose Ui Graphics library and apply this shape onto the surface of your composable.

```
interface Shape {
/**
 * Creates [Outline] of this shape for the given [size].
 *
 * @param size the size of the shape boundary.
 * @param layoutDirection the current layout direction.
 * @param density the current density of the screen.
 *
 * @return [Outline] of this shape for the given [size].
 */
fun createOutline(size: Size, layoutDirection: LayoutDirection, density: 
 Density): Outline
 }
```

As an Example, you can create a rectangle by implementing this interface is

```
class Rectangle(private val roundedCorner: Float = 20f, private val 
pointerLength: Float = 20f) :
Shape {
override fun createOutline(size: Size, layoutDirection: LayoutDirection, 
density: Density): Outline {
    val path = Path().apply {
        moveTo(0f, 0f)
        //line 1 top
        lineTo(size.width, 0f)
     
        //line 2 right
        lineTo(size.width, size.height)

        //line 3 bottom
        lineTo(0f,size.height)
    
        //line 4 left

        lineTo(0f, 0f) //or your can use close()
        //close()
    
       }
      return Outline.Generic(path)
      }
    }
```

Adding rounded corner to it a little bit tricker but once you know how to use [bezier curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve), you can do that easily.

```
class RoundedRectangle(private val cornerRadius: Float = 10f) :
Shape {
override fun createOutline(size: Size, layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
                           density: Density): Outline {
        val path = Path().apply {
        moveTo(0f, 0f)
        //line 1 top
        lineTo(size.width - cornerRadius, 0f)
        quadraticBezierTo(x2 = size.width, y2 = cornerRadius, x1 = 
        size.width, y1 = 0f)
        //line 2 right
        lineTo(size.width, size.height - cornerRadius)
        quadraticBezierTo(x2 = size.width - cornerRadius, y2 = 
        size.height, 
        x1 = size.width, y1 = size.height)

        //line 3 bottom
        lineTo(cornerRadius, size.height)
        quadraticBezierTo(x2 = 0f, y2 = size.height-cornerRadius, x1 
        =0f, y1 
        = size.height)

        //line 4 left
        lineTo(0f, cornerRadius)
        quadraticBezierTo(x2 = cornerRadius, y2 = 0f, x1 = 0f, y1 = 0f)


      }
      return Outline.Generic(path)
    }
   }
```

once you grab of it, you can create the desired shape.

```
class MessageShape(private val cornerRadius: Float = 20f, private val 
pointerLength: Float = 20f) :
Shape {
override fun createOutline(size: Size, layoutDirection: LayoutDirection, 
density: Density): Outline {
    val path = Path().apply {
        moveTo(0f, 0f)
        //line 1 top
        lineTo(size.width - cornerRadius, 0f)
        quadraticBezierTo(x2 = size.width, y2 = cornerRadius, x1 = 
        size.width, y1 = 0f)
        //line 2 right
        lineTo(size.width, size.height-pointerLength - cornerRadius)
        quadraticBezierTo(x2 = size.width - cornerRadius, y2 = 
        size.height-pointerLength, x1 = size.width, y1 = size.height- 
        pointerLength)
        //line 3 bottom
        lineTo(size.width/2f + pointerLength, size.height-pointerLength)
        lineTo(size.width/2f,size.height)
        lineTo(size.width/2f - pointerLength,size.height-pointerLength)
        lineTo(cornerRadius, size.height-pointerLength)
        quadraticBezierTo(x2 = 0f, y2 = size.height - cornerRadius- 
        pointerLength, x1 = 0f, y1 = size.height-pointerLength)
        //line 4 left
        lineTo(0f, cornerRadius)
        quadraticBezierTo(x2 = cornerRadius, y2 = 0f, x1 = 0f, y1 = 0f)
        close()
      }
     return Outline.Generic(path)
   }
}
```

how to use?
apply the shape on to the surface.

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewShape() {
Box(Modifier.size(500.dp)) {
    Image(
        imageVector = ImageVector.vectorResource(
R.drawable.animated_insightful_bulb),
        contentDescription = null
    )

    androidx.compose.material.Surface(shape = MessageShape(), 
    color = Color.Transparent, modifier = Modifier.align(
        Alignment.TopCenter)) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(100.dp)
                .background(color = Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.6f))
        ) {
            androidx.compose.material.Text(
                text = "50",
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
                color = Color.White,
                fontSize = 20.sp
            )
         }
       }
     }
   }
```

[image: output]